# Is it possible to prove the number of extrema in the following function?

Tags: optimization, roots, convex-optimization

I know that the following function might have zero local extrema (when it is strictly increasing), 1 local extremum (when it is increasing and then decreasing) or 2 local extrema (when it is increasing and then decreasing and then increasing again). I want to know if it is possible to show and prove which of these cases happen depending on the values of the coefficients $a,\dotsc,e$, where $a,b,c,d$ are positive real numbers and $e$ is a real number:

$$f(x)=\dfrac{a\log(1+bx)}{cx+d}+ e\log(1+bx), \quad x\geq0$$

I know that the above question is equivalent to showing if $$g(x)=\dfrac{df(x)}{dx}$$ has zero, one or two roots. So, whichever is easier to show, will be fine. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One suggestion would be to switch variable to $u=1+bx$; then $cx+d=\frac cb u + (d-\frac cb)$, and it gets somewhat simpler to see if the roots you find for the derivative are in the domain of the function.

Comment: I have been working on this problem for the last few weeks, but I have not got a good result. I know that for an interval like $[0,x1]$,  when $g(x1)<0$, $g(x)$ has one root in that interval. But I am unable to say what are the conditions for $g(x)$ to have two roots in that interval.